# Must declare a scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, scalar

I was creating a column that will give a me random number but I was getting some  errors.

```
CREATE TABLE tblBookInfo
(
AccessionNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)
 RandomNumber NVARCHAR(10);
 AccNo NVARCHAR(MAX)
 @Upper INT;
 @Lower INT

SET @Lower = 1
SET @Upper = 9999

Select @RandomNumber = Round (((@Upper - @Lower -1)* RAND() + @Lower), 0)

SET @AccNo = 'LIBBOOKS' + RandomNumber
SELECT @AccNo

Set AccessionNumber = AccNo
)
```

ERRORS:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'RandomNumber'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@Lower".
Must declare the scalar variable "@Upper".
Must declare the scalar variable "@Upper".
Must declare the scalar variable "@AccNo".
Must declare the scalar variable "@AccNo".
```

tHank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not very clear what you are trying to accomplish, but here is my **interpretation** of your code in the correct `T-SQL` syntax.
I'm not prepared to guess what you're trying to do below that.

```
CREATE TABLE tblBookInfo 
(   
    AccessionNumber NVARCHAR(MAX),
    RandomNumber NVARCHAR(10), 
    AccNo NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)
DECLARE @Upper          INT, 
        @Lower          INT,
        @RandomNumber   INT

SET @Lower = 1 SET @Upper = 9999

SELECT @RandomNumber = Round (((@Upper - @Lower -1)* RAND() + @Lower), 0)

SELECT @RandomNumber
```